# My SQL search query not distinguishing a column property?

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-like

I have two seperate queries for my database which return search results for two different types of data which are displayed seperately on the search results page.

The two groups displayed are "contacts" and "customers". Customers are contacts in the database that have been given a contact number that is **NOT** zero!

This is a normal query which does not use any **LIKE** statements within the query.

```
$contacts = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT contact.id, first_name, second_name, company_name, email FROM contact INNER JOIN contact_quote WHERE customer_id = 0 GROUP BY first_name, second_name, company_name, email, quote_name ");
$customers = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT contact.id, first_name, second_name, company_name, email FROM contact INNER JOIN contact_quote WHERE customer_id != 0 GROUP BY first_name, second_name, company_name, email, quote_name ");
```

It works fine and displays results into their correct categories.

Like so

[image]

---

**However** My new query which is this

```
$contacts = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT contact.id, first_name, second_name, company_name, email FROM contact INNER JOIN contact_quote WHERE customer_id =0 AND first_name LIKE '%$search%' OR second_name LIKE '%$search%' OR company_name LIKE '%$search%' OR email LIKE '%$search%' OR quote_name LIKE '%$search%' AND contact.id = contact_quote.cid GROUP BY first_name, second_name, company_name, email, quote_name");
$customers = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT contact.id, first_name, second_name, company_name, email FROM contact INNER JOIN contact_quote WHERE customer_id !=0 AND first_name LIKE '%$search%' OR second_name LIKE '%$search%' OR company_name LIKE '%$search%' OR email LIKE '%$search%' OR quote_name LIKE '%$search%' AND contact.id = contact_quote.cid  GROUP BY first_name, second_name, company_name, email, quote_name");
```

Displays all results in both lists even if they are **NOT A Customer**

Screenshot:

[image]

Im guessing there is something wrong in the new query in which It is not able to compare correctly if the column "customer_id" is not equal to zero  and is displaying everything?

To summarise I want to do this:

- Compare with search string
- If any contacts match the search string put them in the contacts query result
- If any customers match the search string put them in the customers query result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parenthesis around your LIKE statements. It's getting to your `WHERE` clause, checks for `customer_id=0 AND first_name LIKE '%$search%'` and then the next it checks `OR second_name LIKE '%$search'` and it won't matter if `customer_id=0` because it's only checking the one case now. By putting the parens around it, it will check `customer_id=0` and then all the LIKES.

```
$contacts = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT contact.id, first_name, second_name, company_name, email FROM contact INNER JOIN contact_quote WHERE customer_id =0 AND (first_name LIKE '%$search%' OR second_name LIKE '%$search%' OR company_name LIKE '%$search%' OR email LIKE '%$search%' OR quote_name LIKE '%$search%') AND contact.id = contact_quote.cid GROUP BY first_name, second_name, company_name, email, quote_name");
$customers = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT contact.id, first_name, second_name, company_name, email FROM contact INNER JOIN contact_quote WHERE customer_id !=0 AND (first_name LIKE '%$search%' OR second_name LIKE '%$search%' OR company_name LIKE '%$search%' OR email LIKE '%$search%' OR quote_name LIKE '%$search%') AND contact.id = contact_quote.cid  GROUP BY first_name, second_name, company_name, email, quote_name");
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why I need to use parenthesis ? is it because its a seperate operation in the query ? Or is it because its a seperate comparison?

Comment: edited my answer above to include a bit more explanation, the parenthesis will group all the likes together so they get evaluated all together with the `customer_id=0 AND (ALL THE LIKES)`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a parenthesis because the first_name,last_name,email,quote_name all have to be to compare with search and then do an AND with the id otherwise quote_name is compared with search and ANDed with the id and others are ORed.